# Can I go back for collectibles after finishing The Sexy Brutale?

Tags: the-sexy-brutale

***Spoilers for the ending of the Sexy Brutale***

At the ending of The Sexy Brutale, you are given a choice.

> Do you to want to restart the day? Yes or no?

I want to select the later option to see what happens. However, I’m worried that my choice will prevent me from going back for the collectibles I missed.

Can I go back to look for invitations and cards after finishing the The Sexy Brutale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, you can return to the mansion after finishing the game.**

After the credits finish, you will be sent to the main menu. If you load your save file, you will return to the mansion at the start of a new day. All Brochure items in the Secrets section will be revealed.

Story-wise, your character awakens:

> Before they smashed the church glass on the upper floor where the game first started.